# When to place elements on a canvas

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas

I am trying to write a tool for testing a graphical application, basically, here is what I do:

1. Create a canvas
2. Create shapes and place them on created canvas.

So, as I am writing an automated testing, I need to wait for the Canvas to be created before I start placing shapes on it, I've used Loaded event, but no shapes were created.

My question is, what's the right moment to start placing elements at the Canvas ? is there a specific event other than Loaded ?

**EDIT**

Ok, in fact its not a Canvas, its a Grid, that acts as a DataTemplate for a ListView, the Grid contains lots of children, I find it hard to get the right moment to say that its finally loaded with all its children.

Perhaps, I shall keep detecting any change in the visual tree for the parent Grid, if no change were detected for some certain of time, then, I presume that all children loaded and viewed ? if I decided to walk this way, what event in the Visual Tree keep get triggered for every new change ?

```
<Grid x:Class="Graphics.Stage.KPage" Name="Scaller"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:aero="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Graphics.Models;assembly=Graphics.Models"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Graphics.Stage"
      Cursor="None"
    xmlns:Header_Footer="clr-namespace:Graphics.Stage.Header_Footer" AllowDrop="True"  Width="{Binding Path=Width}"  Height="{Binding Path=Height}"  >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Graphics.Stage;component/Resources/StageResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Graphics.UserControls;component/SharedDictionaryGreen.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform   ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=PagesList, Path=ScaleX}"
                                         ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=PagesList, Path=ScaleY}"
                        ></ScaleTransform>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>

    <aero:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="ShadowChrome" Opacity="0.75" Margin="0,0,-5,-5"  />  
    <Border  BorderBrush="{StaticResource dark}"  BorderThickness="1.5" Name="PageBorder"   >

            <Grid  Name="Sizer"   >


            <Canvas Name="Layout"  Background="{StaticResource light}" ClipToBounds="True" Cursor="None"/>

            <Canvas Name="ImportedImageLayer"  Background="Transparent" ClipToBounds="True" Cursor="None"/>

            <p:InkSurface  x:Name="LayerInkSurface"  Cursor="None"  />

            <p:TempSurface  x:Name="TempSurface0" Cursor="None"  />
            <p:TempSurface  x:Name="TempSurface1" Cursor="None"  />



            <p:Surface  x:Name="LayerOnTopTools"  Cursor="None"  >

            </p:Surface>


            <p:Surface  x:Name="DraggingSurface0"  Cursor="None" />
            <p:Surface  x:Name="DraggingSurface1"  Cursor="None" />

            <Header_Footer:HeaderFooterView x:Name="MyHeaderView" VerticalAlignment="Top" PictureVerticalAlignment="Top"  MyVerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Header_Footer:HeaderFooterView x:Name="MyFooterView" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" PictureVerticalAlignment="Bottom" MyVerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

            <Canvas  Name="GridsCanvas"  ClipToBounds="True"  IsHitTestVisible="False">

            </Canvas>

            <p:TopViewLayer  x:Name="PageTopView"  ClipToBounds="True" />


        </Grid>

    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of your code?

Comment: I think loaded event fires when you add new elements to the canvas. So, generally, there is no definite time for adding elements.

Comment: I've edited my question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If the `Canvas` is not ready after `Loaded` event perhaps you could try the `ContentRendered` event.

```
 ContentRendered += new EventHandler(MainWindow_ContentRendered);

 private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // do the dew
 }
```